# Как правильно: "эти здания" или "те здания"?

Tags: грамматика, семантика, местоимения

> После встречи  в  поезде  с  художником  я  приехал  в  Ленинград.  Снова
> открылись передо мной торжественные **ансамбли** его площадей и пропорциональных
> зданий.
>
> Я подолгу всматривался в них, стараясь разгадать их архитектурную
> тайну. Она заключалась в том, что (***эти/те***) здания производили  впечатление
> величия,  на самом же деле они были не велики.

Какое указательное местоимение наиболее предпочтительное? Чем они отличаются меж собой?

Повествование идет в прошедшем времени - не логичнее ли говорить "те здания"? (Чтобы "те" отсылали к тем зданиям, которые рассказчик видел; но при этом рассказчик находится уже не у этих зданий). Если "эти" есть в предложении, то "эти" можно из него убрать - смысл не поменяется. Или действительно смысла особого и нет в выборе - "те" или "эти"?

Comment: Это отрывок из Паустовского "Золотая роза", 120 страница

Comment: Это задание с *(эти/те)*, а не 120 страница.

Comment: "Эти" - так как здания были тогда и были когда он писал эти воспоминания(так как они и сейчас есть, очевидно). "Те" можно говорить о чем-то, что перестало существовать на момент повествования. Эти дает бОльший фокус на предмете обсуждения,  без него фраза звучит более размазано.

Comment: "те", кажется, действительно может иметь оттенок прошлого, но как-то этого маловато. Может ли "эти" отсылать к местоимению "них", которое называет ансамбли?

Comment: @Алексей не совсем "оттенок прошлого", а то, чего уже нет. Те, тот - это про чужое, то что не своё, ушедшее, а это, эти про то, что есть. Например: в детстве я ездил в деревню... дворов там было немного,  и многие домишки покосились. я любил ходить среди них, заглядывать в их окна и моё воображение рисовало сказочные картины из жизни крестьян... сейчас на этом место тянутся ввысь новостройки, те покосившиеся домишки остались только в моей памяти. Я не думаю что могут быть отсылки от местоимения к местоимению, местоимение само по себе ничего не значит.

Comment: Паустовский выбрал "эти". Ему виднее. **Этим выражается отношение автора к объекту.**

Comment: Вот я и хочу узнать, что значат "эти" в контексте, могло ли быть "те".

Comment: @Алексей я считаю, что употребление те тут почти невозможно, так как нарушится логический императив повествования. О чем история? О знаниях - поэтому эти. История об этом. Если история о воспоминания, других зданиях, о том что нога зачесалась - тогда "те". Если история о том, то дальнейшее условие не является причиной повествования, а является некой ширмой, коробкой, в которой внутри то самое - это. Не автор вспомнил те здания, а эти здания впечатлили автора и поэтому он их вспоминает...

Comment: @Алексей "Те" там тоже звучит, так что могло. В контексте это значит, что эти здания ему нравятся (нет дистанцирования от себя за счёт "те").

Comment: А ещё что это важно для рассказчика. Неважное можно дистанцировать.

Answer (score 1):

#### Разница между <kbd>эти</kbd> и <kbd>те</kbd>

- <kbd>те</kbd>  показывает какую-то отдалённость рассказчика от объекта:

  - Физическую. Например:

  ```
  Видишь те здания? (рассказчик не рядом со зданиями)
  ```

  - Или временную:

  ```
  Те здания не нравились мне. (рассказчик уже не видит здания)
  ```
- <kbd>эти</kbd> показывает некую близость:

  - Временную и физическую одновременно. Например:

  ```
  Эти здания мне не нравятся. 
  (рассказчик находится рядом со зданиями в настоящем времени)
  ```

  - Близость в воспоминаниях (когда рассказчика нет рядом с объектом, но он очень подробно вспоминает об этом объекте, описывает его):

  ```
  Высотки - это кошмар для меня. Они такие огромные, такие пыльные!  
  Эти здания мне совсем не нравятся.
  ```

#### Выбор автора

В приведённом вами тексте больше всего подходит пункт "Близость в воспоминаниях". Поэтому Паустовский и выбрал местоимение <kbd>эти</kbd>:

> После встречи в поезде с художником я приехал в Ленинград. Снова
> открылись передо мной торжественные ансамбли его площадей и
> пропорциональных зданий. 
> Я подолгу всматривался в них, стараясь разгадать их архитектурную тайну.
> Она заключалась в том, что **эти** здания производили впечатление
> величия, на самом же деле они были не велики.

Могло ли быть <kbd>те</kbd>? Могло, но это не так хорошо бы звучало, с <kbd>эти</kbd> смысл лучше передаётся, передаётся глубина воспоминаний автора и его чувства.

Comment: В примере про высотки "эти", потому что говорится за высотки в общем, а не за конкретные высотки. "Те" нельзя использовать, когда речь о виде (вид зданий).

Comment: Высотки - это кошмар. Те здания, о которых говорится выше, мне совсем не нравятся.

Comment: @user190920 Это уже попытка обхода. "Те" указывает на конкретные здания. Такой пример: *Мне не нравятся змеи. Те животные очень опасные.* Здесь стилистика, а не грамматика, не по вашей части.

Answer (score 0):

**Эти** для отсылки в тексте к чему-то близкому по тексту или контексту. **Те** для более дальней отсылки. По факту, они в 99% взаимозаменяемы. В примере Паустовского лучше все же использовать **эти**, так как на них идет ссылка в начале предложения (в местоимении **них**). Это примерно как сказать:

```
Эти здания очень хороши, те здания я люблю.
```

Сравните с

```
Те здания очень хороши, эти здания я люблю.
```

Comment: *По факту, они в 99% взаимозаменяемы* — очень протестую. Когда впервые говорится о чём-то, что не находится рядом, только "тот" подходит. Когда много о чём-то говорится, только "этот" подходит. И ещё много всего.

Answer (score -1):

Автор говорит о петербургских зданиях вообще, без конкретизации. Потому, на мой взгляд, местоимение может быть здесь опущено:

"Она заключалась в том, что здания производили впечатление величия..."

Выпалывание лишних слов служит улучшению стиля. И если есть возможность без ущерба удалить какое-то слово, это следует сделать.

Comment: Без местоимения пропадает акцентуация, фраза становится аморфной и пресной.

Comment: То что можно выпилить - это понятно. Но вопрос был: в чём разница междку двумя местоимениями? И кстати, Паустовский не выпилил, а выбрал `эти`.

Comment: "Выпилывание лишних слов служит улучшению стиля. И если есть возможность без ущерба удалить какое-то слово, это следует сделать" - слова придают красоту и точность речи.

Comment: @Зонтик Я не сказал "выпиливание". Я сказал "выпалывание". (К вопросу о стиле...)